# Postman POST working but AngularJS post throwing 404

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm just trying to pass some basic form data through to a web-api via AngularJS $http.

here is the function that called to send data to the API:

```
    $http({
        url: "/Portal/GenerateTimeSheets",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: angular.toJson($scope.placementForm),
    }).then(function (response) {

    }), function(response) {

    };
```

Note: if I breakpoint and copy and paste the $scope.placementForm data into postman it works completely fine, but going through a browser is throwing errors.

Here is my api:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void GenerateTimeSheets([FromBody]PlacementModel placement)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STUB");
    }
```

and the Placement Model:

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "candidateName")]
    public string CandidateName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientName")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "jobTitle")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "placementStartDate")]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "placementEndDate")]
    public string EndDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "frequency")]
    public string TimeSheetFrequency { get; set; }
```

Comment: 404 means the path you request is wrong

Comment: The path is 100% correct, thats why is confusing me @Sajeetharan

Comment: that is very strange then, can i see the screenshot of the network tab

Comment: If possible post the request data being shown in postman and the one shown in the devtools network tab.

Comment: what is the request in the devtools? Most likely the path is wrong

Comment: I seriously need to look in more detail before posting. You are correct @Sajeetharan, the path was missing /api/ to suffix it.

Comment: @CeriWestcott ok posted hope it might help others

Comment: Please share the complete api controller

Comment: @CeriWestcott if you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

404 Usually denotes that the url of the request is wrong, You are missing something in the url. Validate your url with the backend. Hope it helps